# Sort array based of startTime & endTime

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I got an array of objects containing a fromTime & endTime. I would like to sort those in order to get 16:00-18:00 first in the array and 16:00-21:00 last. I know how to filter based on the endDate however I need to take the fromDate into account, could anyone help me in the right direction?

```
"deliverySlots": [
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "17:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "19:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "18:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "20:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "19:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "18:00",
    }
]

function compare(a,b) {
    var time1 = parseFloat(a.deliveryToTime.replace(':','.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
    var time2 = parseFloat(b.deliveryToTime.replace(':','.').replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''));
    if (time1 < time2) return -1;
    if (time1 > time2) return 1;
    return 0;
}   
deliverySlots.sort(compare);
```

Goal:

```
"deliverySlots": [
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "18:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "17:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "19:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "18:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "20:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "19:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
]
```

So basicly I want to prioritize sorting on endDate & then startDate. 16:00 - 21:00 should come AFTER 19:00-21:00

Comment: Why is 16-21 last and not, for example 19-21? It's not clear what the logic should be, can you please be more precise?

Comment: why is `16:00-21:00` last? please add a sorted result as well.

Comment: So basicly I want to prioritize sorting on endDate & then startDate. 16:00 - 21:00 should come AFTER 19:00-21:00

I have updated my first post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to sort your object by their properties values such as below:

```js
var deliverySlots = [
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "17:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "19:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "18:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "20:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "19:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "21:00",
    },
    {
        "deliveryFromTime": "16:00",
        "deliveryToTime": "18:00",
    }
];


function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.deliveryToTime < b.deliveryToTime || (a.deliveryToTime == b.deliveryToTime && a.deliveryFromTime > b.deliveryFromTime))
    return -1;
  if (a.deliveryToTime > b.deliveryToTime || (a.deliveryToTime == b.deliveryToTime && a.deliveryFromTime < b.deliveryFromTime))
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

deliverySlots.sort(compare);

console.log(deliverySlots);
```

Comment: So basicly I want to prioritize sorting on endDate & then startDate. 16:00 - 21:00 should come AFTER 19:00-21:00

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I am confusing myself... :P

Answer (score 1):

You could get the length of the events and then sort by start and end time.

```js
const getMin = s => s.split(':').reduce((a, b) => a * 60 + +b);

var deliverySlots = [{ deliveryFromTime: "17:00", deliveryToTime: "19:00" }, { deliveryFromTime: "18:00", deliveryToTime: "20:00" }, { deliveryFromTime: "19:00", deliveryToTime: "21:00" }, { deliveryFromTime: "16:00", deliveryToTime: "21:00" }, { deliveryFromTime: "16:00", deliveryToTime: "18:00" }];

deliverySlots.sort((a, b) => {
    var aa = [a.deliveryFromTime, a.deliveryToTime].map(getMin),
        bb = [b.deliveryFromTime, b.deliveryToTime].map(getMin);

    return (aa[1] - aa[0]) - (bb[1] - bb[0])
        || aa[0] - bb[0]
        || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(deliverySlots);
```